# Will B450 + Ryzen 5 3400G display in 1440p 144Hz

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, amd-radeon, displayport, amd-ryzen

I currently have a 1440p 144Hz monitor with Ryzen 5 2600 and an Nvidia GPU, the system currently is able to display 1440p at 144Hz.

However, I am looking at swapping the Ryzen 5 2600 (which contains no onboard graphics) with a Ryzen 5 3400G, and getting rid of the discrete graphics card.

Will there be any challenge I might run into with the onboard graphics and motherboard in terms of displaying 1440p 144Hz (for desktop environments only and not gaming)?

The motherboard is an MSI B450I GAMING PLUS AC which has an onboard DP port which is the one I shall be using, however the website states

> 1 x DisplayPort, support a maximum resolution of 4096x2304 @60Hz, 2560x1600 @60Hz, 3840x2160 @60Hz, 1920x1200 @60Hz1,2
> ....
> Only support when using Ryzen™ with Radeon™ Vega Graphics and 2nd Gen AMD Ryzen™ with Radeon™ Graphics/ Athlon™ with Radeon™ Vega Graphics processors
> Maximum shared memory of 2048 MB

Although it states 60Hz on the website, but it will support up to 4096x2304

If anyone has experience with this type of set up it will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will never get the performance from integrated graphics as a discrete graphics card.

Ok, so for desktop work ONLY it won't be terrible.

However, I doubt the integrated GPU supports 144hz.  60hz is probably the max.

The other thing to consider is if you plan to do anything that has OpenCL or CUDA support as the discrete graphics card will also boost those functions.  More and more software leans on the GPU for assistance, so long term this is probably a bad idea.

The documentation says it support HDMI 1.4 which doesn't support 1440p@144hz without compromises.  You need 4:2:0 compression so your going to lose color details.  So displayport probably suffers similarly with this motherboard.

[https://www.mini-itx.com/~B450I-GAMING-PLUS-AC](https://www.mini-itx.com/%7EB450I-GAMING-PLUS-AC)

Suggest it supports DisplayPort 1.2 if this is true then you can support 1440p at 144hz.  I don't know what there source of information so I can't say how reliable it is.

Comment: I will probably believe it has DP 1.2 just because of the age of the board, so let's say the integrated GPU supports 1440p@144hz, is there anything else might get in the way of the setup?

Comment: @ThatLeo Given your only doing desktop work, you should mostly be fine.  If you were doing anything GPU accelerated that part will be slower.  Any software you run that supports OpenCL or CUDA will be slower to some degree.  Many things use GPU acceleration now, but your web browser and etc should be fine.  Complex PDF might render slower in Adobe Reader.